How to inspect where a variable value is set?
M-x describe-variable exwm-randr-workspace-monitor-plist returns:
...
exwm-randr-workspace-monitor-plist is a variable defined in ‘exwm-randr.el’.

Its value is (0 "VGA1")
Original value was nil
...

So I tried ripgrepping my complete sytem for this value: rg --hidden '(0 "VGA1")'
Where is this variable set?

Who knows? Start with emacs -Q to check that you are setting it (explicitly or implicitly) and it's not some default value. I also check with emacs -q: sometimes default.el or site-start.el might be setting things - use (locate-library "site-start") to find it. Then search your init files and the packages you load.  I use the XDG convention, so my init.el file and elpa subdirectory are in ~/.config/emacs, as is my (empty) early-init.el file, so I just have to search there for any of my settings.

I would search for VGA1 in case the variable is set in pieces. I would also search for x?randr in case it is set using a shell command. If worse comes to worst, I would add a variable watcher in my early-init and restart emacs: see Running a function when a variable is changed for information, but note that there are some limitations. And don't forget to delete the watcher afterwards: watching a variable is relatively expensive, so you don't want to run with it all the time.

This question is similar to: Tracking when variables get updated. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
